# Why is Android Studio generating duplicate gradle dependency automatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3 on Windows 10. I already have these in my dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

But these lines are always auto generated in gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.+'
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
}
```

Gradle Version: 3.3
Android Plugin Version: 2.3.3

How do it stop Android Studio from generating these unnecessary dependencies and why is it doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are also facing this.

I have found out that whenever we create an `Activity` using the Activity creation wizard with

New -> Activity

this line:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
}
```

is added automatically to build.gradle file.

And

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.+'
}
```

is added automatically whenever we create a `Fragment` using

New -> Fragment

Even if dependencies are already added.

I have not found any solution to prevent it so for now I am removing those manually after the Activity/Fragment are created.